# Calculating the vector to intercept a falling object

Tags: vectors, 3d, classical-mechanics

Given two objects with known positions in a three dimensional space, of which:

- One is a ballistic projectile (that is, it is free-falling with constant gravitational acceleration), and
- The other (the "catcher") is not subject to gravity and may travel in any direction with some constant speed (and instantaneous acceleration),

I want to calculate the vector that the catcher must travel along in order to intercept the falling projectile.

I've got as far as formulating the problem into equations as follows:

$$
\mathbf{P_i} = \mathbf{P_p}  + \mathbf{U_p} t + \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{G} t^2
$$
$$
\mathbf{P_i} = \mathbf{P_c} + \mathbf{V_c} t
$$

where:

- $\mathbf{P_i}$ is a 3-dimensional vector describing the position of intercept
- $t$ is a scalar representing the time of intercept relative to the start time.
- $\mathbf{P_c}$ and $\mathbf{P_p}$ are (known) 3-dimensional vectors describing the initial positions of the catcher and the projectile, respectively.
- $\mathbf{U_p}$ is a 3-dimensional vector describing the initial velocity of the projectile.
- $\mathbf{G}$ is a 3-dimensional vector describing the acceleration of the projectile due to gravity.
- $\mathbf{V_c}$ is a 3-dimensional vector describing the velocity of the catcher required to reach $\mathbf{P_i}$ at time $t$. Its magnitude is known, but not its direction.

Obviously, finding any one of $t$, $\mathbf{P_i}$ or $\mathbf{V_c}$ is sufficient to solve the problem.

Combining the two equations above to eliminate $\mathbf{P_i}$ gives me a quadratic equation in $t$, but with vector co-efficients, which I haven't a clue how to even begin solving. Can anyone help me out? Is there something missing from or incorrect about my approach here?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your approach, but the "catcher" can catch the object at any point on its trajectory, i.e., *there are infinitely many solutions*, parameterized by the time $t$ of interception.

Comment: Sorry, I perhaps didn't make it clear enough that the catcher's speed is limited. That is, $|\mathbf{V_c}|$ is some known constant value (10 m/s, say). It's entirely possible that the projectile is simply too far away or too fast for the catcher to reach from its starting position with its velocity, and there are no solutions. But I want to know how to determine that, and how to find a solution if one exists.

Comment: Oh, I see that in the description of ${\bf V}_c$ now. Anyway, using the knowledge of that magnitude one can extract a polynomial in $t$ (with known coefficients) whose solutions are the possible "catching" times; in particular this guarantees that there are at most finitely many solutions. Please see my answer for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To tackle the difficulty of dealing with a vector system, we can exploit the fact that we know all of the vectors except ${\bf V}_c$, and that we know the magnitude $V_c := \left\vert\left\vert{\bf V}_c\right\vert\right\vert$ to produce a scalar equation in $t$.

As indicated in the question, at the time $t$ we can equate the positions of the projectile and the catcher:
$${\bf P}_p + {\bf U}_p t + \frac{1}{2} {\bf G} t^2 = {\bf P}_c + {\bf V}_c t.$$
Rearranging gives $${\bf V}_c t = {\bf Q}(t)$$
where ${\bf Q}$ is some quadratic polynomial in $t$ whose coefficients are known (in fact, ${\bf Q}$ is just the position of the projective relative to the initial position of the catcher). Thus, if we take the dot product of each side with itself we get
$$V_c^2 t^2 = ({\bf V}_c t) \cdot ({\bf V}_c t) = {\bf Q}(t) \cdot {\bf Q}(t).$$
But now, as desired, we have produced a *scalar* equation in $t$, namely (after rearranging), $${\bf Q}(t) \cdot {\bf Q}(t) - V_c^2 t^2 = 0,$$ whose coefficients are all known. This is quartic in $t$, so we may have up to four solutions (and we can always find exact expressions for them, though in general these are not very nice). Since the leading coefficient of the l.h.s. is $\frac{1}{4} {\bf G} \cdot {\bf G} > 0$, we can test whether there are any solutions by finding its critical points (a quartic always has at least one) and checking whether it is $\leq 0$ for at least one of them.

Comment: This may give you four solutions but all could be invalid.

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you mean by invalid here, but the procedure involving the critical points of the quartic is used precisely to see whether any solutions are real. One could also impose a physical condition like $t \geq 0$, though OP doesn't mention this, and it's anyway easy to modify the test to restrict attention to such solutions.

Comment: That's a pretty clever use of the dot product. Seeing as this eliminates the unknown terms to give a quartic in $t$, I'm marking this as the answer because it does constitute a theoretical solution.

In practice, however, "not very nice" is a bit of an understatement. Even with this technique, I've struggled to complete the solution to find a practical answer to the problem. I've ended up just finding a "good enough" solution. I realise that's anathema to math purists, but for visitors interested in that solution, I've descibed it [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/109899/73219).

Comment: @4026 If one is only interested in a numerical solution, one can still applying this line of thinking, i.e., compute the quartic (which is computationally cheap), and use a numerical root solver, and finding numerical roots of polynomials is especially well-studied. (In particular, coding an exact solution is unwieldy and inefficient and requires using complex numbers, even when your desired solutions are real.) In fact, the method you describe on gamedev.se is essentially a single application of Newton's Method, which is the prototypical numerical root finder.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to solve for $t$. You want to solve for $V_c$. This gives the required velocity vector for the catcher to catch it at an unspecified time $t$ later.

If you are instead given $V_c$ then you could solve for $t$. However the vast majority of values of $V_c$ would result in no solution.

Comment: What you say is true - $\mathbf{V_c}$ is the ultimate answer I want - but finding the value of $t$ (Or $\mathbf{P_i}$) would allow me to determine the value of $\mathbf{V_c}$ very simply. However, I'm unsure about how to solve for $\mathbf{V_c}$ directly; can you provide any insight on that?

Comment: The problem is that $v$ and $t$ are related. You can not find one without knowing the other Consider the 1D version: $v\times t=s$. Given a distance $s$ you can not determine $t$ or $v$ without knowing the other.